# Why is /boot empty on nfsboot nfs host, when files exist on booted client?

Tags: boot, nfs, root-filesystem

I am confused to say the least. Where are these files kept?

So, isc-dhcp server, providing network boot and tftp server records. A
tftp host providing an initrd and vmlinux image over pxelinux.0. An 
nfs host providing nfs root to previous vmlinux kernel.

I have an existing kernel and initrd that boot correctly. On the booted client machine there is a literal `/boot/` directory with literal files within it.
The nfs host does not have any files in its `/path/to/nfsroot/boot/` directory. The nfs client can be powered off and on again, and the boot directory will be populated after reboot, the files in the /boot/ directory appear to have no correlation to the tftp provided ones. (`Binary files /path/to/tftp/vmlinuz-4.9.0-3-amd64 and /path/to/nfs/boot2/vmlinuz-4.9.0-4-amd64 differ`)

I've copied the /boot directory to /boot2 in to identify that someonthing is weird with the /boot directory.
There doesn't appear to be a mount line for /boot.

---

on the nfs host, the boot directory is a mount
`/dev/sda1 on /path/to/nfs/boot type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)`; what possible use is this mount line?, cause sda1 is already mounted to /: `/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)` (I might have caused said weird mount with a messed up bind mount attempt)

Answer (score 0):

red herring, the boot directory was cleared by a reversed bind mount on the nfs, my bad.